# Force JVM to load and initialize classes preemptively to reduce lag?

Tags: java, performance, jvm, classloader

In a large Java desktop application I'm a developer on, I've noticed that, when you've just started the program, most GUI features and operation lag for a bit when you first activate them. Click the same feature a second time and it snaps into effect instantly. My current hypothesis is that one or more of the following runtime operations cause this effect (in approximate order of most to least likely from my knowledge):

- Loading the .class files off disk (or decompressing them from the JAR)
- Class bytecode verification
- JIT compilation of bytecode
- Class static initialization

It would obviously be better if the program had that lovely snappy feel on everything, not just buttons you've already clicked at least once. So, questions I have are:

1. How can I tell which of these operations (or perhaps some other operation that I haven't thought of) is the primary contributing factor? I know how to use VisualVM for CPU and heap profiling, but I don't know how to profile semi-hidden JVM factors like this.
2. Assuming the above operations are the cause of this lag, one way to reduce it might be to have a low-priority background thread run through all of the classes in the program and the most-frequently-used libraries and touch them reflectively to force them to be classloaded and initialized. Ideally, it would touch frequently-used classes first and relegate less-commonly-used classes to later in the process. Is this a good idea?
3. If so, has anyone already written something that does this?
4. If not, what's the easiest way to implement it?

Comment: There is the `-Xverify:none` option. Not sure how safe this is however...

Comment: What you could to find out why the delay is: see which resources are peaking when you click one of the buttons: is it IO, CPU, network? That could give you a hint where to look.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828662/why-doesnt-the-jvm-load-classes-from-a-database) and its comments say that the I/O time dominates the CPU factors like class verification.

Comment: @bluevoid I don't know of a good profiling strategy when each operation takes (usually) under a second and you can only perform a handful of tests before you have to restart the VM to try again. For example, VisualVM only updates its CPU graph at 1 second intervals. There's just too much noise going on to get useful data from that.